# Does Neo4j supports sharding

Tags: neo4j

I have found some answers on stackoverflow where it is said that Neo4j does not support sharding. But those answers are very old. In 2019, does Neo4j supports sharding. Please provide correct links or explain it in details.

Old answers:

1. [Is there a way to shard and replicate neo4j data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234891/is-there-a-way-to-shard-) 
   and-replicate-neo4j-data
2. [Neo4j sharding aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558589/neo4j-sharding-aspect)

If Neo4j supports sharding how it can be implemented.

Comment: You may want to consider what you're actually trying to achieve with sharding. Here's a video from Adobe showing how they were able to go from 125 Mongo servers to 48 Cassandra servers to finally 3 Neo4j servers in a causal cluster for increased performance and capability. Although Neo4j doesn't do sharding, remember that sharding is just one approach you can use in pursuit of actual objectives such as performance, availability, disaster recovery, and so forth. So instead of just seeing if Neo4j can check the sharding box, consider if Neo4j can check the actual needs you're after.

Comment: And here's that link [Harnessing the Power of Neo4j for Overhauling Legacy Systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPM9hVorPSM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neo4j does not support sharding.

Instead, for high availability, the Enterprise Edition supports [causal clustering](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/introduction/), which supports a number of read-write "core servers" and multiple read-only "replica servers".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @cybersam